# How to have a div rather than a button for pivot link

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I want to customize  a `PivotItem` to make it close-able (kind of like browser tabs).

I provided a custom  `onRenderItemLink` implementation do display an `X` icon on the right side of the tab, and an `onClick` method on that icon that will close the tab.

The main issue I'm facing is that this `PivotItem` is wrapped with a `button` (`Pivot.Base.tsx` renders a `Commandbutton`), that intercepts all onClick events on `Firefox`.

Firefox does not allow onClick events under a Button (this seems to be in accordance with the standard, so it's not considered a bug), so i can never close a tab on Firefox.

Is there any way to force Fabric UI to create a div rather than a button in this scenario?

Is there any other way to force a div there (some way to intercept what fabric ui creates and switch the button with a div)?

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up closing the tab if the button was clicked on its right side

```
const clickX = clickEvent.pageX;
const buttonRight = clickEvent.currentTarget.offsetLeft + clickEvent.currentTarget.offsetWidth ;
if (buttonRight - clickX <= 40) {
  removeTab(tab);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? Is this in onLinkClick callback? I have tried it but offsets seem wrong

Comment: @partyelite it's onLinkClick for the <Pivot> element